# Handling of const char* on ESP32

Tags: c++, esp32

I'm working on making some Spotify API calls on an ESP32. I'm fairly new to C++ and while I seem to got it working how I wanted it to, I would like to know if it is the right way/best practice or if I was just lucky. The whole thing with chars and pointers is still quite confusing for me, no matter how much I read into it.

I'm calling the Spotify API, get a json response and parse that with the ArduinoJson library. The library returns all keys and values as `const char*`
The library I use to display it on a screen takes `const char*` as well. I got it working before with converting it to String, returning the String with the getTitle() function and converting it back to display it on screen. After I read that Strings are inefficient and best to avoid, I try to cut out the converting steps.

```
void getTitle()
{
// I cut out the HTTP request and stuff
        DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);
        DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, http.getStream(), );
        JsonObject item = doc["item"];

        title = item["name"];  //This is a const char*

}
```

```
const char* title = nullptr;

void loop(void) {

    getTitle();

    u8g2.clearBuffer();
    u8g2.setDrawColor(1);
    u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_6x12_tf);
    u8g2.drawStr(1, 10, title);
    u8g2.sendBuffer();
}
```

Is it okay to do it like that?

Comment: If you are using C++, forget raw pointers and use std::string. You get `title` being a dangling pointer.

Comment: I suggest you learn pointers

Comment: @S.M. this is a "small" platform (low speed and memory) and the asker has stated they want to make their code more efficient (in this case by avoiding unnecessary copying)

Comment: I had it working with strings before (the String class should be Arduino's adaptation of std::string). Now I try to avoid that. A little more information regarding what/where to learn about pointers?

Comment: Strings are very efficient. You save only 4 bytes on each string object and get many problems with raw pointers. As I said you are getting a dangling pointers, you have to copy pointed C strings to the heap. Let string objects to do this best.

Comment: @S.M., this is Arduino String. it fragments the heap and there is no memory manger to defragment it

Comment: @Juraj this is not an issue in this particular example, when OP needs to copy the char array to the heap in any case.

Comment: @S.M. So I should do something like `String getTitle() {}` and then later on use `myTitleAsString.c_str()`  ?

Comment: It's correct if Arduino strings support the move semantic, otherwise there are options.

Answer (score 4):

#### This is not fine.

When seeing something like this, you should immediately become suspicious.

This is because in `getTitle`, you are asking a *local* object (`item`) for a pointer-- but you **use** the pointer later, when the `item` object no longer *exists*.

That means your pointer might be meaningless once you need it-- it might no longer reference your data, but some arbitrary other bytes instead (or even lead to crashes).

This problem is independent of what exact library you use, and you can often find relevant, more specific information by searching your library documentation for "lifetime"  or "object ownership".

#### FIX

Make sure that `item` (and also `DynamicJsonDocument`, because the documentation tells you so!) both still exist when you use the data, e.g. like this:

```c
void setTitle(const char *title)
{
    u8g2.clearBuffer();
    u8g2.setDrawColor(1);
    u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_6x12_tf);
    u8g2.drawStr(1, 10, title);
    u8g2.sendBuffer();
}

void updateTitle()
{
    DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, http.getStream(), );
    JsonObject item = doc["item"];

    setTitle(item["name"]);
}
```

See also: https://arduinojson.org/v6/how-to/reuse-a-json-document/#the-best-way-to-use-arduinojson

### Edit: If you want to keep parsing/display update decoupled

You could keep the JSON document "alive" for when the parsed data is needed:

```c
/* "static" visibility, so that other c/cpp files ("translation units") can't 
 * mess mess with our JSON doc directly
 */
static DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);
static const char *title;

void parseJson()
{
    [...]
    // super important to avoid leaking memory!!
    doc.clear();
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, http.getStream(), );

    // TODO: robustness/error handling (e.g. inbound JSON is missing "item")
    title = doc["item"]["name"];
}

// may be nullptr when called before valid JSON was parsed
const char* getTitle()
{
    return title;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I get what you're trying to say. My problem with this is, I want to call `u8g2.drawStr()` every 60ms to get a scrolling text effect. But I don't want to call the API and the json stuff that often. So I wanted a "intermediate" variable where I can store the title, but I don't know how to do that with your solution.

Comment: The downside of this is that it computes `doc["item"]["name"]` every 60 milliseconds. I have a feeling that's a pretty expensive operation. It seems like it would be a good idea to cache that somewhere.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Good point, I edited the answer!

Comment: Thank you guys, what about the way it was done in the link @radioflash posted? `strlcpy(data.name, doc["name"] | "N/A", sizeof(data.name));`

Comment: @t3ahunt3r That works-- but still performs an unnecessary copy, so that is kinda halfway between the std::string approach (copies data, dynamically allocates memory) and the solution above (no dynamic memory allocation, no copying after parsing). In practice, this is all probably premature optimization and using std::string would've been perfectly fine ;)